# Reading in datetime pandas without having to convert

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a very big file, and I want to know if it is possible to read in a CSV (which had a datetime column when it was written) so that the datetime column reads in as a datetime, not a string.  The problem is that it takes about 4 hours to convert using pd.to_datetime after it is read in.

Suppose the df is `df`.  The file is `df.csv`

The date column is `df.date`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, take a look at the `parse_dates` option in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html). For example:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

data = """
date,   c1
2012-07-31 02:00, 1.1
2012-07-31 02:15, 2.2
2012-07-31 02:30, 3.3
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), parse_dates=['date'])
```

Check with:

```
>>> df.dtypes
date    datetime64[ns]
 c1            float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Also, if the column happens to be the index, simply set `parse_dates=True`